# Can't get my if statement to work?

Tags: java, android, xml

I know this has got to be simple. But for the life of me i don't know why i can't get this right.

Ok so I want to go from a listview page (got that) then click a switch to make it go to the next page (also got that.) Then I want a int to tell me which position I am on form the last page (might be working?) now i can't get the If Else statement to work in the page.

```
public class NightmareParts extends Activity
{
    public int current_AN_Number = NightmareList.AN_position_num;
    private TextView edit_title;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.part_layout);

        // isn't working here. Why?
        // test_edit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.directions_tv);        
        // test_edit.setText(R.string.directions_text_two);                 
        // works without this being in here. 

        setDoneButtonListener();
    }

    //Set up the Done button to initialize intent and finish
    private void setDoneButtonListener()
    {
        Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void editTitle()
    {
        if (current_AN_Number = 1)
        {
            edit_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.part_title);           
            edit_title.setText(R.string.AN_title_1);                        
        }           
    }
}
```

The current_AN_number is coming from the last page.

Comment: please note the error is saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean"

Comment: When you need to add something to your post, such as "please note the error is saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean"", please just edit your answer instead of commenting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `if` statement is incorrect:

```
if (current_AN_Number = 1)
```

You've used the assignment operator, when you wanted to compare it with the `==` operator:

```
if (current_AN_Number == 1)
```

Comment: @OrhanC1 It's good practice to tag the guys name so he gets a notification, Orhan.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. Yo, @HankBates; You got mail, son!

Comment: @mikeyaworski, I'm not loving the one tag per comment thing :/

Answer (score 1):

```
if (current_AN_Number = 1)
```

Should be

```
if (current_AN_Number == 1)
```

You're not *setting* `current_AN_Number` to be 1, you are *comparing* if it is equal to 1. So use `==`.

Answer (score 0):

```
test_edit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.directions_tv);
```

is not working because `test_edit` is never declared.

Comment: yes that was some other stuff for later. It was set for comments.